# Pointers & Arrays Pointing Array issue

Tags: c++, arrays

Firstly, Sorry about my bad english.
I wanna ask something that I expect amazing. I'm not sure this is amazing for everyone, but It is for me :)
Let me give example code

```
char Text[9] = "Sandrine";
for(char *Ptr = Text; *Ptr != '\0'; ++Ptr)
cout << Ptr << endl;
```

This code prints

```
Sandrine
andrine
ndrine
drine
rine
ine
ne
e
```

I know it's a complicated issue in C++. Why İf I call Ptr to print out screen it prints all of array. However if Text array is a dynamic array, Ptr prints only first case of dynamic array(Text). Why do it happen? Please explain C++ array that how it goes for combination of pointing array.

thanks for helping.

Comment: Because there's a special output handler for `const char *`.

Comment: could you specify what kind of dynamic array you mean?

Comment: @KillianDS e.g char* myarray = new char("play");

Comment: @chris did you mean that Text is const char that point all of arrays elements?

Comment: @burakim ah, but that's not an array.

Comment: @KillianDS Why? It seems to me this is a array that is allocated dynamic.

Comment: `new char("play")` doesn't create an array! Instead, it should fail to compile: there is no way to construct a `char` from a `char const*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing particular special about arrays here. Instead, the special behavior is for `char const*`: in C, pointers to a sequence of characters with a terminating null characters are used to represent strings. C++ inherited this notion of strings in the form of string literals. To support output of these strings, the output operator for `char const*` interprets a pointer to a `char` to be actually a pointer to the start of a string and prints the sequence up to the first null character.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
char Text[9] = "Sandrine";
```

the "Text" is an address in memory, it is the starting address of your string and in its first location there is a 'S' followed by the rest of the characters. A string in C is delimited by a \0 i.e. "S a n d r i n e \0"

When you write

```
for(char *Ptr = Text; *Ptr != '\0'; ++Ptr)
  cout << Ptr << endl;
```

when the for loop runs the first time it prints the whole string because Ptr points to the start of the string `char* Ptr = Text` when you increment Ptr
you are pointing to the next character Text + 1 i.e. 'a' and so on once Ptr finds `\0` the for loop quits.